# ¿ Cómo detectar idioma del dispositivo en Unity?

Tags: string, unity, idioma

Estoy haciendo un juego en Español pero si lo descargan de otro país no lo entenderán por lo que tengo que hacer que detecte idioma del móvil y elija el `string` dependiendo el idioma. ¿Se hace como en `Android Studio` ? No he encontrado información al respecto...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la documentación no miente :), se usa [[docs]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-systemLanguage.html):

```
SystemLanguage lang = Application.systemLanguage;
Debug.log(lang.ToString());
```

que devuelve un elemento de la enumeración SystemLanguage. [[docs]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemLanguage.html).

Ahora para tratar el idioma desconozco si existe tal utilidad igual que en Android. Por lo que he visto no de parte de Unity, si de terceros.

Comment: A la hora de comparar el systemLanguage con "English" por ejemplo, qué pongo? "EN" o "English" o que se pone? O si quiero ruso, con que hay que comprarlo? En docs eso no lo he visto.

Comment: debes compararlo con la enumeración del tipo System language, el segundo link. debería ser algo como `SystemLanguage.English == Application.systemLanguage`, aunque si usas un switch debería funcionar también

Comment: Vale , he puesto esto:    ``if (SystemLanguage.English == Application.systemLanguage) `` ``{
   texto_idioma.text = "Hello"; 
  }`` Como declaro ``texto_idioma`` ? He puesto en Unity un gameobject con una variable ``public GameObject miVariable;`` Pero no me aclaro al relacionar ambas cosa, porque nunca he puesto un texto desde codigo, siempre lo he puesto desde mismo unity. Como ``GUItext``?

Comment: ? Está así bien? Estoy intentando asignar al GUItext en Unity a ``texto_idioma`` pero no me deja.

Comment: Si tienes la variable guitext, debes asignarle tu string `texto_idioma.text = "Hello";` para obtener texto_idioma debes usar `gameObject.GetComponent<GUIText>();`. ahora mismo no tengo una computadora con unity para darte una respuesta precisa :P

Comment: Puedes abrir chat? Así en 5 min lo tengo listo, porque no me esta dejando

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/56616/unity

Comment: Era poner como Tipo ``Text`` mi variable ``texto_idioma`` y   ``texto_idioma.text = "NEW RECORD";``